# Telegram bot not responding after upload files and database on heroku

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm a beginner of python. Below is my python code for telegram bot. It's working on XAMPP but I would to host the bot on cloud so that there's no need to start the XAMPP's Apache & MYSQL everytime when I'm trying to use the bot. However, it's not working after it's been uploaded to Heroku. May I know how can I fix this ? Thank you in advance.

Modified for uploading to Heroku

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import os
import mysql.connector

from typing import Dict

from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, Update, ReplyKeyboardRemove
from telegram.ext import (
    Updater,
    CommandHandler,
    MessageHandler,
    Filters,
    ConversationHandler,
    CallbackContext,
)
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host='us-cdbr-east-05.cleardb.net',
user='b081bd520f9623',
passwd='557dad71',
database='heroku_26b1a208f24f1fa')

query = mydb.cursor()

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
TOKEN = '5333685233:AAFr4-1nB6_I8ZMdt25Y4zBotHRA9I_qtMI'

# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi! This is start')

def help(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')

def sql(update, context):
    sql = "SELECT nama_item, jumlah_dalam_kg FROM data_penjualan_harian WHERE nama_item = 'Lemon'"
    query.execute(sql)
    sql_result = query.fetchall() 

    pesan_balasan = ''
    for x in sql_result:
        pesan_balasan = pesan_balasan + str(x) + '\n'

    #memperbagus balasan bot
    #menghilangkan tanda petik
    pesan_balasan = pesan_balasan.replace("'","")
    #menghilangkan tanda kurung
    pesan_balasan = pesan_balasan.replace("(","")
    pesan_balasan = pesan_balasan.replace(")","")
    #menghilangkan tanda koma
    pesan_balasan = pesan_balasan.replace(",","")

    update.message.reply_text(pesan_balasan)

def main():

    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))

    # on noncommand i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # # Start the Bot
    updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                      port=PORT,
                      url_path=TOKEN,
                      webhook_url='https://powerful-lowlands-14039.herokuapp.com/' + TOKEN)

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You should revoke all the credentials that you posted as port of your code snippet.

Comment: I had tried different method but nothing works. Is there any solution for me ?